# $C_G(x)$ in a solvable group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=PQ$ be a solvable group with $P$ and $Q$, P- and q-sylow subgroup of $G$ respectively. Suppose both $P$ and $Q$ are not normal and $C_G(P)=Z(G)$ and $C_G(Q)>Z(G)$. Let $x\in C_G(Q)-Z(G)$. So $Q\leq C_G(x)$. Is it true that such $x$ is a $q$-element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. SmallGroup(1296, 670) is a very strong counterexample. $x$ could be an element of order $p^2$.

The action of $P$ on $Q$ does not have to be related to the action of $P$ on $P$.

Comment: If by $q$-element you mean an element whose order is a power of $q$, then there are much smaller counterexamples. I took it to mean $q$-singular element, an element whose order is divisible by $q$.

Comment: Order $p$ is also possible for $x$, SmallGroup(1296, 695).

Comment: Now, I found an example of order 96 by GAP. $x$ is a p-element.($o(x)=p^\alpha$).

Comment: Cool. My search was $2^a 3^b$ with $b \leq a+1$ and ordered by $a$, so I got to 1296 before 96. :-)